# Rolling a dice until one value has been rolled 1 000 000 times

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, dice

I'm writing a program which rolls a dice n-times and stops as soon as one of the six possible outcomes has been rolled 1000000 times. The results are stored in an array. Unfortunately, my code doesn't stop at the right time I think there's something wrong with the while-loop.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Wuerfel {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random randomNumber = new Random();

        int[] rolledNumbers = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

        while (rolledNumbers[0] < 1000000 || rolledNumbers[1] < 1000000 || rolledNumbers[2] < 1000000 || rolledNumbers[3] < 1000000 || rolledNumbers[4] < 1000000 || rolledNumbers[5] < 1000000) {

            int roll = randomNumber.nextInt(6) + 1;
            switch (roll) {
                case 1:
                    rolledNumbers[0]++;
                case 2:
                    rolledNumbers[1]++;
                case 3:
                    rolledNumbers[2]++;
                case 4:
                    rolledNumbers[3]++;
                case 5:
                    rolledNumbers[4]++;
                case 6:
                    rolledNumbers[5]++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First tip: you really want that switch to be `rolledNumbers[roll - 1]++` :))

Comment: Hint: You don't need to check all sides when one is incremented. Only check the side you just incremented to see if it reached 1,000,000.  You could change from a `while` to a `do...while`.

Comment: You need break statements after each of the case-clauses.

Comment: Yeah thats a great idea. the do-while combined with rolledNumbers[roll-1]++ would mean that a switch isnt needed anymore

Answer (score 1):

### Hint 1

`true || false || false || false || true` resolves to **true**. Consider this hint whilst you think about the condition in your `while` loop.

### Hint 2

switch statements fall through by default. So, if the roll is `1`, **every** `rolledNumbers[i]` is incremented, not just `rolledNumbers[0]`. Add a `break` to the end of every case batch. Alternatively, think about how you can write a one-liner that accomplishes the same thing the entire `switch` block is supposed to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You should use logical operator && instead of || in your while loop condition,

and also add breaks after each case statement.

Answer (score 0):

Of-course, if you can use [switch-expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/switch-expressions.html) then you don't need `break` in your `switch`.

```java
import java.util.Random;

public class Wuerfel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        int[] rolledNumbers = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        while (true) {
            int roll = randomNumber.nextInt(6) + 1;
            int index = switch (roll) {
                            case 1 -> 0;
                            case 2 -> 1;
                            case 3 -> 2;
                            case 4 -> 3;
                            case 5 -> 4;
                            case 6 -> 5;
                            default -> -1;
                        };
            if (index >= 0) {
                rolledNumbers[index]++;
                if (rolledNumbers[index] >= 1_000_000) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Idle_Mind just demonstrating the existence and use of _switch-expressions_. Of-course you can implement the task without a `switch` at all.

Comment: thank you, really appreciate your answer!

Comment: I tried but it says I dont have enough rep to vote :S

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation based on my original comment:

> Hint: You don't need to check all sides when one is incremented. Only
> check the side you just incremented to see if it reached 1,000,000.
> You could change from a while to a do...while.

Code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random randomNumber = new Random();

    int[] rolledNumbers = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    int roll;
    do {
      rolledNumbers[roll = randomNumber.nextInt(6)]++;
    } while (rolledNumbers[roll] < 1000000);

    for(int s=0; s<rolledNumbers.length; s++) {
      System.out.println("Side " + (s+1) + ": " + rolledNumbers[s]);
    }    
    System.out.println("Side " + (roll+1) + " wins!");
  }
```

Sample Output:

```
Side 1: 999182
Side 2: 999885
Side 3: 1000000
Side 4: 999669
Side 5: 999952
Side 6: 999426
Side 3 wins!
```

Note that in this line:

```
rolledNumbers[roll = randomNumber.nextInt(6)]++;
```

We assign a random value (between 0 and 5 inclusive) to `roll`, and the result of that assignment is also immediately used to access the `rolledNumbers` array.  This works because an [assignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26) in Java also produces a "result":

> At run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of
> the variable after the assignment has occurred. The result of an
> assignment expression is not itself a variable.